# Extracting message content from JSON using regular expresions

Tags: c++, json, regex

I need to extract content of messages from JSON, I am not allowed to use JSON parser so I tried using regular expressions, however I got stuck on extracting message content. I am using C++.

Here's an example of the JSON file:

```
{
   "id":"776752463986294785",
   "type":0,
   "content":"\"",
   "channel_id":"762106839054811176",
   "author":{
      "id":"487706666905894923",
      "username":"Emzak",
      "avatar":"a70859ecda1355dfd55bddcfd0194458",
      "discriminator":"6235",
      "public_flags":0
   },
   "attachments":[
      
   ],
   "embeds":[
      
   ],
   "mentions":[
      
   ],
   "mention_roles":[
      
   ],
   "pinned":false,
   "mention_everyone":false,
   "tts":false,
   "timestamp":"2020-11-13T10:16:58.777000+00:00",
   "edited_timestamp":null,
   "flags":0
}
```

as I said i need the Content field, my current regex is :

```
"content"[ :]+(\"[^"]*\")
```

Which works unless there are quotation marks in the content. If there are any, they are always escaped, but I haven't found a way to get past them. With quotation marks my current regex gives me this string :

```
"content": "\"
```

Which would be problematic if there was any message behind that quotation mark. I would like to get this string :

```
"content": "\""
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it escape `\"` as follows:

```
"content"[ :]+(\"(?:\\.|[^"])*\")
```

It creates a non-capturing group that matches every `\` with the following character, as well as the original `[^"]` criteria.